# Only allow trusted applications for OAuth2 API

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

Say I have an API where users can log in through OAuth2. What are my options for allowing only trusted applications to interact with parts of this API? For example, I would like to have a mobile app and a web app, but I don't want anyone else developing apps that would interact with this API.

In other words, how do Facebook, Twitter and Instagram keep people from just cloning the client id from their mobile apps and using their entire APIs as if they were the official app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## WHO AND WHAT IS ACCESSING THE API SERVER

Before I address your question I would like to make clear the distinction between **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing the API server.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that you can authenticate,authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID or OAUTH2 flows.

Now you need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling your API server and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server, is it really your genuine mobile app or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

Well to identify the **WHAT** developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app and some go the extra mile and compute it at run-time in the mobile app, thus becomes a dynamic secret in opposition to the former approach that is a static secret embedded in the code.

## THE PROBLEM

> Say I have an API where users can log in through OAuth2. What are my options for allowing only trusted applications to interact with parts of this API?

You found yourself a very hard problem to solve...

If your API only serves mobile apps you can keep your wording, but from the moment you create an API that needs to server web apps you cannot apply anymore the wording `allowing only trusted applications` and you will have to satisfy yourself with something around `preventing access of unauthorized applications`.

The problem with web apps is that you only need to inspect the web page source code with the browser dev tools to be able to extract any secret used to identify the web app to the API server.

With mobile app some developers have the misconception that once they are released as binary that is not possible to extract secrets or is very hard... Well lets see how the `strings` command in Linux can help us:

```sh
$ strings -aw app-debug.apk | grep -C 1 '_API_' -
ic_launcher_round
GRADLE_API_KEY
GRADLE_ENV_API_KEY
abc_action_bar_home_description
```

You can prevent the above by obfuscating the code when you create the release, but then we just need to use some more sophisticated tooling like the Mobile Security Framework(MobSF) that uses under the hood a set of other open source tools to de-compile the binary and perform static analysis on it to enumerate all attack vectors and expose secrets embed on the code.

[Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

So anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you can learn more on [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques. This articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC and TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

## PREVENT API ABUSE

> In other words, how do Facebook, Twitter and Instagram keep people from just cloning the client id from their mobile apps and using their entire APIs as if they were the official app?

I don't know what they use specifically to prevent API abuse with the cloned identifiers, but anyone that wants to protect their APIs from being abused by non official clients will use Web Application Firewalls(WAF) and User Behavior Analytics(UBA) solutions that employ machine learning and artificial intelligence to detect bad behaviors and block their access to the API.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

The problem with this approach is that is based on a negative detection model that tries to identify the bad guys based on patterns and it tends to have false positives, that leads to relax the blocking policies to avoid leaving out the legit users, meaning that some bad guys will always find their way through.

## A POSSIBLE SOLUTION

> For example, I would like to have a mobile app and a web app, but I don't want anyone else developing apps that would interact with this API.

### For a Web App

For your web app I would use [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) across all pages of the website in order to let Google to distinguish humans from bots. This detection is done in the background without requiring interaction with the user.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

This on its own will not be enough and will also have false positives, once is a negative detection model, but is a good start to leave at bay the script kids.

For the most determinate attackers you will need to employ the already mention WAFs and UBAs solutions, and this ones will be more complex to deploy and maintain, but once more they work in a best effort basis and will not be able to eliminate the API abuse.

### For Mobile Apps

#### Limit and Hide Secrets

The first step is to limit secrets in your mobile to only one, the one used to access your API server and all other third part services you need to access from your mobile app you should delegate to the API server, thus not exposing in the mobile app the keys to access your third part services.

You can see [this repo](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets) for a dummy Android APP that I created for my next blog post(not published yet), that shows the several techniques to hide secrets. Spoiler alert, the best approach in Android is [this one](https://github.com/approov/android-hide-secrets/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp):

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "api_key.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_criticalblue_androidhidesecrets_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    // To add the API_KEY to the mobile app when is compiled you need to:
    //   * copy `api_key.h.example` to `api_key.h`
    //   * edit the file and replace this text `place-the-api-key-here` with your desired API_KEY
    std::string JNI_API_KEY = ANDROID_HIDE_SECRETS_API_KEY_H;

    return env->NewStringUTF(JNI_API_KEY.c_str());
}
```

Bear in mind that the above technique is good only to make very hard to extract the secret with static analysis of the binary.

The easiest way to extract secrets used by a mobile app is for an attacker to mount a man in the middle attack to the mobile app in a device he controls, with a tool like:

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

With this tool the attacker will add a custom ssl certificate to the device and mobile app in order he can intercept and read all https traffic, thus being able to understand how the communication happens between the mobile app and the API server in order to mount an automated attack.

#### Code Obfuscation

When building the release binary always obfuscate the code, for example Android Studio
has built-in support for it or alternatively you can use commercial tooling to achieve even better results.

#### Certificate Pinning

When pinning the connection between the mobile app and the API server we prevent the man in the middle attacks from occurring, because the mobile app will refuse connections that are not using the certificate from the API server.

[Certificate Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

> Pinning is the process of associating a host with their expected X509 certificate or public key. Once a certificate or public key is known or seen for a host, the certificate or public key is associated or 'pinned' to the host. If more than one certificate or public key is acceptable, then the program holds a pinset (taking from Jon Larimer and Kenny Root Google I/O talk). In this case, the advertised identity must match one of the elements in the pinset.

#### Mobile App Attestation

The use of a Mobile App Attestation solution will enable the API server to know WHAT is sending the requests, thus allowing to respond only to requests from a genuine mobile app while rejecting all other requests from unsafe sources.

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

So this solution works in a positive detection model without false positives, thus not blocking legit users while keeping the bad guys at bays.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at [Approov](https://approov.io/approov-in-detail.html)(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## CONCLUSION

In the end of the day is all about how much valuable is the data you have, what are the impacts for the business of a data breach, and what are the regulations you need to comply with for that data, like GDPR in Europe.

So based on this assessment you need to decide how many layers of defense you want to put around your API serving web and mobile apps.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! So, as I understand it, I can only make it harder for someone to clone my API keys, but there is no real way to completely block that, right?

Comment: To extract the API keys yes... to block them of being used by attackers it is pretty hard with APIs that support web apps, but not that hard with mobile APIS when using a mobile app attestation solution.